# Check if pointer to base class is one of derived with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, variadic-templates

I have a polymorphic type Base which is the base-class of many other types:

```
class Base
{
 Base() {}
 virtual ~Base() {}
};
```

One of the derived class contains a value, that is templated by type T.
This class can also contain a pointer to another instance of that class, _stub,  which may be of another type T, to act as a replacement of the value.
The restriction is that the other type must be one of the supported types indicated by the variadic templates. 
So _stub is either of type T or of one of SupportedTypes.

What I would like the *getValue* function below to do is to return _v of type T if _stub is NULL, otherwise dynamic_cast *_stub* to its original derived type (let's say X), and cast it away to T.
The requirement is that the type X must have a cast operator to T.

The _stub is guaranteed to be either T or one of SupportedTypes.

```
template <typename T, typename... SupportedTypes>
class Generic : public Base
{
public:

 Generic(): _v() {}
 virtual ~Generic() {}

 virtual T getValue() {
       if (_stub) {
         // Attempt dynamic_cast on _stub to type T or 
         // any of SupportedTypes until we find its original type X

        // I'm looking for a solution that would look like the following line
         X* p = dynamic_cast<T,SupportedTypes...>(_stub.get());
         assert(p);
         return (T)*p->_v;
       }
       return _v; 
 }

private:
 T _v;
 std::shared_ptr<Base> _stub;
};
```

Originally, I had no SupportedTypes parameter pack, and I would specialize getValue() for the type T and do a chain of dynamic_cast, but this was dependent on each type T and every function similar to getValue() would need this cascaded if/else dynamic_cast soup.

I was trying to experiment with the variadic templates SupportedTypes so that I could come up with a nicer solution where the derived class would only have to indicate the types _stub might be in a single place.

Does anyone have a clean solution to this problem ?

Solution:

I actually went with boost::variant thanks to the hint of @apple apple

Comment: are you trying to achieve something like `std::any`?

Comment: This is impossible. Here `X* p`, the type `X` cannot be determined at compile-time.

Comment: @liliscent it could be also a recursive variadic template struct that each hold a pointer to one of SupportedTypes, where each struct of type X would have a function "template <typename T> cast() {(T)dynamic_cast<X*>(_stub.get())->_v;} Isn't it possible to achieve with recursive variadic parameter unpacking ? I'm not looking for a function that would remove the dynamic_cast entirely, just that it would return me a value of type T at a single place

Comment: The template you wrote in the comment is very different to the question. For the question, you don't have a fixed type, it's impossible. But for the comment, it can be trivially achieved by variadic template, as long as the `T` is a fixed type.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that this is happening inside a related class `Generic` and has the possibility of using another value if the pointer is null is irrelevant.  What you want is a function template that converts to a single type derived from `Base` via `dynamic_cast` to one of a set of other types similarly derived:

```
class B;

// The real work:    
template<class T>
T convert(B *b) {return static_cast<T&>(*b);}
template<class T,class U,class... Rest>
T convert(B *b) {
  if(U *u=dynamic_cast<U*>(b)) return *u; // converted to T
  return convert<T,Rest...>(b);
}

// Example hierarchy:    
struct B {virtual ~B() {}};
struct X : B {};
struct Y : B {};
struct S : B {                  // convertible from other types
  S() {}
  S(X) {}
  S(Y) {}
};

// Example usage:    
S getS(B *b) {return convert<S,X,Y>(b);}
```